# Java String Split() Method

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering what the following line would do:

```
String parts = inputLine.split("\\s+");
```

Would this simply split the string at any spaces in the line? I think this a regex, but I've never seen them before.

Comment: Have you tried for yourself?

Comment: That would give a Type Mismatch because `String#split` returns a `String[]` and not just a `String`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as [documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) `split` takes regex as argument.

In regex `\s` represents [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of containing whitespace characters like:

- tab `\t`,
- space `" "`,
- line separators `\n` `\r`
- more...

`+` is [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) which can be read as "*once or more*" which makes `\s+` representing text build from one or more whitespaces.

We need to write this regex as `"\\s+` (with two backslashes) because in String `\` is considered special character which needs escaping (with another backslash) to produce `\` literal.

So `split("\\s+")` will produce array of tokens separated by one or more whitespaces. BTW trailing empty elements are removed so `"a b  c ".split("\\s+")` will return array `["a", "b", "c"]` not `["a", "b", "c", ""]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though actually *any number* of space meta-characters (including tabs, newlines etc). See the [Java documentation on Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

It will split the string on one (or more) consecutive white space characters. The [`Pattern` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) describes the Predefined character classes (of which `\s` is one) as,

> Predefined character classes
>
> ```
> .     Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
> \d    A digit: [0-9]
> \D    A non-digit: [^0-9]
> \s    A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
> \S    A non-whitespace character: [^\s]
> \w    A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
> \W    A non-word character: [^\w]
> ```

Note that the `\\` is to escape the back-slash as required to embed it in a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it splits both tab and space:

```
String t = "test your   function      aaa";

for(String s : t.split("\\s+"))
   System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

> ```
> test
> your 
> function
> aaa
> ```